# Realtime calculation of new COVID cases with Survey123 and AGOL Dashboard without using database join

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, coronavirus

Like many COVID dashboards there is usually a metric showing the total number of new cases for the current day. Apart from manually editing this field, is there a way of automatically calculating this metric using survey123 and arcade?

Logically this cannot be achieved using a field calculation as this has to be manually triggered and would just be a static calculation. It must require some kind of database view which compares the dates at the time of the query, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in updating hosted feature layer. There is a way with Windows Scheduler which will trigger python script every X min.

Logic is to do this via REST API + some python scripting.

Links which may be useful:

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/update-features.htm
https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/add-features.htm
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/updating-features-in-a-feature-layer/

Comment: Thanks. So there is no easy way in survey123 forms then?